# Show $AA^T-(X^T X)^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite where $AX=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Show $AA^T-(X^T X)^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite where $AX=I$. $A, X$ may not be invertible or square.

Attempt: One way is to check $$AA^T-(X^T X)^{-1}=$$$$\bigg(A-(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\bigg)\bigg(A-(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\bigg)^T$$
which is not hard if come up with this equality first. I feel this is like complete square with respect numbers but without a general procedure to follow. How do one complete square with matrices in general? Are there any more intuitive approach to the proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach. To prove that
$$
v^TAA^Tv\ge v^T(X^TX)^{-1}v
$$
for every vector $v$, write $v=X^Tu$ for some vector $u$ (in fact, we may take $u=A^Tv$). Thus the problem boils down to showing that
$$
I\ge X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T,
$$
but this latter inequality is evident because $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is an orthogonal projection.

You may also rewrite the above solution in the form of completion of square (well, it actually isn't a square, but a Gram matrix):
\begin{aligned}
AA^T-(X^TX)^{-1}
&=A\left[I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right]A^T\\
&=A\left[I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right]\left[I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right]A^T\\
&=\left[A-(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right]\left[A-(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right]^T.
\end{aligned}
The moral: try to exploit the use of orthogonal projections.